# Анимация WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

По клику хочу переместить label в какие-то координаты, помогите с кодом, вот что-то пытался делать по книге, но там затухание только :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.From = 1.0;
            animation.To = 0.5;
            animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            label1.BeginAnimation(???, animation);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThicknessAnimation anim = new ThicknessAnimation();
            anim.From = new Thickness(10,20,20,30);
            anim.To = new Thickness(256, 20, 20, 30);
            anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            label1.BeginAnimation(Label.MarginProperty, anim); 
        }
```

Comment: Собственно Margin - это не очень хорошее решение по производительности, поскольку изменение марджинов будет вызывать перестройку интерфейса и новый Measure/Arrange. 
Лучше анимировать RenderTransform